# div box size css show the value of auto

Tags: javascript, css

Help is really wanted here, I have a div surrounding a `textarea`, the `div` is `auto` sized, height and width, and I need to know what that auto value is. tried a little javascript, please see below:

```
function textAreaChange() {

var textboundary = document.getElementById("textarea");
textboundary.style.height = document.getElementById("heightx").innerHTML;
textboundary.style.width = document.getElementById("widthy").innerHTML;

}
```

fairly new to all this javascript so please be patient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at obtaining the height and width, based on wrapping of the text area, try one of the following:

```
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').offsetHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').scrollHeight;
```

**clientHeight** includes the height and vertical padding.

**offsetHeight** includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

**scrollHeight** includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

There are Widths that correspond to each Height.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :)

```js
function textAreaChange() {

    var textboundary = document.getElementById("textarea");   
    document.getElementById("heightx").innerHTML = textboundary.offsetHeight; 
    document.getElementById("widthy").innerHTML = textboundary.offsetWidth;

}
textAreaChange();
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" ></textarea>

<div id="heightx"></div>
<div id="widthy"></div>
```